# SQL union throw error 1064 but queries run successfully independently

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my query

```
select CONCAT(`name`,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')
from OCCUPATIONS
order by name
union
select CONCAT('There are a total of ',count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupation),'s.')
from OCCUPATIONS
group by Occupation
order by count(Occupation),Occupation asc
```

Error received is

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union
select CONCAT('There are a total of ',count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupati' at line 4

If I run these two query separately , it works but not sure why union isn't working. I tried union ALL as well.Any clue?

Comment: Remove the `order by name` from the first query. You order the entire result, not the individual unions.

Comment: Also, your query looks odd. Maybe you should try [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute the below SQL script? I think it doesn't need "UNION" to remove those duplicate records.

```sql
select CONCAT(`name`,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')
from OCCUPATIONS
union all
select CONCAT('There are a total of ',count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupation),'s.')
from OCCUPATIONS
group by Occupation WITH ROLLUP;

-- order by name
-- order by count(Occupation),Occupation asc;
```

Comment: This add a NULL at end.

Comment: whats the significance of --